# Why does this armature move in a weird semicircular motion?

Tags: animation, armature

I applied transformations to both the armature and the mesh but whenever I play the animation the dog still goes in this semicircular motion. I want it to stay in original location.

[image]

PS. the mesh and the animated armature are imported as FBX (it is already made by someone else)

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hello, I posted a new question regarding the same project. Could you please take a look? It's got the blend.file. Thanks!!!!   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215098/why-is-the-animation-not-working-properly-after-i-sculpted-a-pre-rigged-mesh