# Why is the animation not working properly after I sculpted a pre-rigged mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

so a client asked me to resculpt this wolf cub mesh that he purchased online into a dog.

The wolf cub mesh comes pre-rigged and animated in Unity.

After I sculpted it into a dog and parent it to the armature in Blender the animation has slight deformation no matter what I tried. I reassigned vertex groups, applied transformation but still.

[image]
Deformations occure around frames 17 to 25 where the original wolf blinks.

The client wants me to make sure that the animation will work exactly the same with this edited mesh in Unity.

I have no experience in Unity but can anybody please tell me what I can do to make the newly edited mesh works smoothly with the original armature? I will attach my blend.file down below!

Here is a screenshot of the weight painting of the right eyelid. The right eye has even more influence on the face.

[image: weight paint of the eye/lid]

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/LsPlNL20

Comment: Does the problem only happen in Unity? Or in Blender also? Not everyone here uses Unity, so not everyone will be able to test your file if the problem is only in Unity.

Comment: Welcome to BSE! This is a Q&A site to help you and other people that have the same problem. It's a good idea to add some screenshots to your questions to give people who can help you and those who have a similar problem a quick overview  I just did that so we can see the deformations and the weight paint.

Comment: I took a quick look at the blend file to add some screenshots. It looks like the wolf blinks around frame 20 and you have changed the positions of the eyes. Now the eyelids pull in the mouth when the dog blinks. The eyes also have too much influence. Can you add a screenshot of the wolf around frame 20? You probably have to move the bones for the eyes and lids or change their weight paint.

Comment: Oh, and you have your mesh parented to 2 armatures. Have a look at the modifier stack.